Related to definite integral using equation from table of integrals
I am having the following equation:
$P_1 = \int_0^{\infty} \gamma(m_0, \frac{\phi m_0}{\Omega_0 h})\cdot h^{m_1-1} \cdot e^{-\frac{m_1}{\Omega_1}h}\text{d}h$ --- (1)
where $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is lower incomplete Gamma function, $\phi, m_0, m_1, \Omega_0$ and $\Omega_1$ are constant.
To solve this equation, I am using the equation 6.455 (2) from book table of integrals. This equation is as follows:
$\int_0^{\infty} x^{\mu-1}\cdot e^{-\beta x} \cdot \gamma(\nu, \alpha x ) \text{d}x = \frac{\alpha \Gamma(\mu + \nu)}{\nu(\alpha + \beta)^{\mu +\nu}} {}_2F_1\bigl(1,(\mu+\nu);\nu+1;\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\bigr)$ ----(2)
My query is that can we compare equation (1) with this equation (2).
I am getting the doubt because in (1), $h$ in lower incomplete Gamma function is in denominator while in (2), $x$ in lower incomplete Gamma function is in numerator.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated...

Unfortunately, you are correct in your doubt. The two integrals are not of the same form. The result does not apply to your case.

Thank you so much sir for your response.....Could u pls suggest a way to solve the integral in equation (1)....

So can we say that it is not possible to solve such equation (1)....

It unclear what you even mean by "solve" here. For any particular values of its constants, you can calculate the value of the integral to any non-zero accuracy you like, using standard techniques. This may seem like something lesser than a formula like the one here, but it isn't. You cannot do any better calculating a value from that formula. And just because one formula you found failed to provide what you want doesn't mean that there must be no formula at all. Why do you need a specific formula here? Most mathematics only needs to know a value exists, not exactly what it is.

Thanks a lot sir for ur reply....My intention of saying "not possible to solve " is that can we say that we cannot obtain closed form expression for eq.(1)

My comment still applies. The failure of one formula to be applicable in your case is nowhere near to being enough to say that it is impossible. And I ask again, do you really need a formula here, other than the integration itself? It is very common for people to become obsessed with finding closed-form expressions, even when such expressions offer nothing that is really helpful for them. Often calculation of values from their "closed form" is no easier than calculation from the integral. There are uses for closed forms, but they are rarer and less necessary than students often believe.

Ok sir... Thanks a lot once again...
